# Unable to cast constrained generic interface reference to covariant interface reference

Tags: c#, covariance

I'm trying to understand how covariance works with generic type constraints and it seems like the constraints are ignored for no obvious reason.

Consider the following code:

```
    public interface IContainer<out T> { }

    public interface IContents { }

    public class Food : IContents { }

    public class Foo
    {
        public void Bar<T>() where T : IContents
        {
            IContainer<IContents> x = null;
            IContainer<T> y = null;
            IContainer<Food> z = null;
            x = y; // Cannot convert source type 'IContainer<T>' to target type 'IContainer<IContents>'
            x = z; // Valid
        }
    }
```

Why does compiler produce 'Cannot convert' error on `x = y` and produce no error on `x = z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# does not support variance for value types - see the [variant generic interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces#declaring-variant-generic-interfaces)  doc:

> `ref`, `in`, and `out` parameters in C# cannot be variant. **Value types also do not support variance**.

i.e. the following will not work:

```
public struct MyStruct : IContents
{
}

var structContainer = (IContainer<MyStruct>)null;
IContainer<IContents> x = structContainer;
```

Since `T` is not constrained neither to `class` not to `struct` it can be either reference type or value type, so in general case `IContainer<T>` is not assignable to `IContainer<IContents>`.

Add `class` constraint to the `Bar` method:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar<T>() where T : class, IContents
    {
        IContainer<IContents> x = null;
        IContainer<T> y = null;
        IContainer<Food> z = null;
        x = y; // Now Valid
        x = z; // Valid
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem, but the question still stands :)

Comment: @KhaldinK.S. I've quoted the part of the doc which explains it.

Comment: Great. I understand it works this way because there is no way to know during compile time how much memory should be allocated to whatever x methods or properties might return - reference size or some arbitrary value type size.

Comment: @KhaldinK.S. the thin is that generics are compile time thing, so _"there is no way to know during compile time how much memory should be allocated"_ is not fully correct. But yes, the fact that generic methods are compiled for each value type should be related to this limitation.